# Unable to extend ProfileFOSUser1Controller of sonata symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am working in symfony sonata admin. I am trying to extend ProfileFOSUser1Controller but unable to extend it. I have tried by clearing the cache also but didn't work? This is my controller code:

```
<?php

  namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Controller;

  use Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileFOSUser1Controller as BaseController;
 /**
 * Overwrite methods from the ProfileFOSUser1Controller if you want to change the behavior
 * for the current profile
 *
 */

 class ProfileUserController extends BaseController
 {


  /**
  * @throws AccessDeniedException
  *
  * @return Response|RedirectResponse
  */
  public function editAuthenticationAction()
  {
    echo "here"; die;
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->get('sonata.user.authentication.form');
    $formHandler = $this->get('sonata.user.authentication.form_handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('sonata_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sonata_user_profile_show'));
    }

    return $this->render('SonataUserBundle:Profile:edit_authentication.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, I have changed the class name to the same name as base class have: changed "ProfileUserController" to "ProfileFOSUser1Controller". Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/bundles/inheritance.html)
I think your controller name should be ProfileFOSUser1Controller